# infinite loop example with minimum code in c#

Tags: c#, .net, infinite-loop

Can you give me an infinite loop example on c# with minimum code? I came up with something but I thought there could be more easier way.

Comment: What have you tried? I have a feeling there will be 10 answers by the time I've posted this comment...

Comment: You mean, like `while(true){}`?

Comment: why do you want an infinite loop? There are probably better ways of doing what you want.

Comment: I'm curious. What exactly did you come up with?

Comment: Interesting that most people are suggesting `while(true){}`. I would have said that `for(;;){}` is the idiomatic way of doing this in C#.

Comment: @Cody: I thought about `for(;;){}` but for me it looks unnaturally because  `for(int i;..` itself is for looping with current position explicit state. So when no position is required, `while(true)` is more suitable.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I would hazard a guess that it's easier to remember the `while` construct because it's an actual English idiom (e.g. while I am here you do this) whereas there isn't a common idiom for `for`.

Comment: @skyfoot I need it because of the demonstration purpose.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The typical examples are the for and while loops. For example

```
for(;;)
{}
```

and

```
while(true)
{}
```

However, basically any looping construct without a break or a terminating condition will loop infinitely. Different developers have different opinions on which style is best. Additionally, context may sway which method you choose.

Answer (score 11):

```
while (true);
```

That should be enough.

The generated IL is:

```
IL_0000:  br.s        IL_0000
```

The code unconditionally transfers control to itself. A great way to waste CPU cycles.

Answer (score 9):

Infinite loop:

```
while (true)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

to break it:

```
while (true)
{
    if (condition)
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need a bit more obscurity, this might be what you are after:

```
for (;;) { }
```

Or even

```
l: goto l;
```

Answer (score 3):

In the spirit of Code Golf:

```
for(;;);
```

Answer (score 3):

Though not exactly an infinite loop, this will have the same practical effect and consume WAY less CPU. :)

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, an example of infinite loop.

```
while(true)
{

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Call a method within the same method and you have an infinite loop happening (*Only conditions force you to break the loop*)

```
void HelloWorld()
{
   HelloWorld();
}
```

Comment: This is not an infinite loop, this is infinite recursion, which will in most cases result in a StackOverflowException.

Comment: I was just bout to write something like that

Comment: This will cause `StackOverflowException`

Comment: We all know what happens if you do this!

Comment: Well you assumed the OP wanted an example in the literal loops, by the way recursion is also a loop (maybe not in the context what you imagine now)

Comment: If tailoring occurs this will also run endless (but this depends on the compiler).

Comment: yes, this will cause a stack overflow in any system where the stack has a size limit, or where there is no TCO. `while(true)` will eventually be forced to end too, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: `while(true);` won't end til the thread is aborted.  There's no code that can throw an exception, and no way to stop it outside of killing the thread (or firing up a debugger).

Comment: The OP wanted an `infinite loop with minimum code` no explicit mention of without exceptions or Time Frame. Different perspectives for the solution !

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Recursion is not looping. While it's sometimes possible to emulate particular looping logic with recursion (and vice versa), that does not mean that they are equivalent. This is not an infinite loop.

Comment: @Adam: so something that goes around in a cycle isn't a loop? Interesting. Recursion isn't iteration, but it can be looping. This recursion is looping.

Comment: @Adam: The danger of exception doesn't bother me, since the question doesn't seem to have a good reason behind it. The semantic difference we seem to have is that: I see a loop as something that goes around, you see a loop as something that goes around and you can stop. We'll have to agree to differ.

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Thing is, on a language/platform without tail call optimization (read: almost all of them), eventually a recursive "loop" has to stop due to exhausting all its stack space.  By definition, something that ends is not infinite.

Comment: @cHao and with that definition there's no infinite loops at all. No loop will run forever. Inresponsive programs get terminated at some point. A definition of "infinite" loops should take those into account

Comment: They might get terminated, but they don't terminate themselves.  If left entirely to itself on stable hardware, an unconditional empty loop *will indeed* run forever.  A recursive solution, on the other hand, sets up (and relies on!) the conditions that will eventually lead to its own failure, and thus can not continue forever, and thus can not be considered "infinite" by *any* stretch of the word's meaning.